# output a vector bool in columns?

Tags: for-loop, vector

I am trying to find out how to output a vector (with a lot of numbers stored) in a nice table-like way in the console.

What I did so far is the following:

```cpp
void output(const vector<bool>& numbers, int width, int columns){
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        if (numbers[i] == true){
            cout << setw(width) << i;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I tried to write a function to display a certain constant range of `i` each new line. I know I can divide the size of the vector by `columns`. Example: If the vector has 100 numbers stored, and I divide it by 5 columns, then I would basically need 20 rows to realize 5 columns. That means I want the code to output only 5 numbers from vector in each line, which would result in 20 lines with 5 numbers each line (that makes 5 columns).

I will be honest here, I absolutely have no clue how to do this. I tried to find tips and tricks, and I know I somehow should work with `/` or even `%`, and also maybe a nested loop, but I can't figure out how. The tips and tricks I found on the web were all about some `matrix[i][j]` thingies, which I don't understand. My vector doesn't even have `[i][j]`.

Maybe it makes sense to mention, that I am only allowed to use the following libraries: `<vector>`, `<iomanip>`, `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your loop before outputting each number:

```cpp
if ((i != 0) && ((i % columns) == 0)){
    cout << "\n";
}
```

You also need to output something, even if just a blank string, when `numbers[i]` is false, so that `std::setw()` does its job correctly for each row/column, otherwise your table won't look correct.

```cpp
if (numbers[i] == true){
    cout << setw(width) << i;
}
else{
    cout << setw(width) << "";
}
```

So, for example:

```cpp
void output(const vector<bool>& numbers, int width, int columns){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        if ((i != 0) && ((i % columns) == 0)){
            cout << "\n";
        }
        cout << setw(width); 
        if (numbers[i] == true){
            cout << i;
        }
        else{
            cout << "";
        }
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/LDJXgh)

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. I had a mistake and forgot to delete a certain line. Now it works properly. Thank you for that genius code! By any chance, do you have an idea how I could change the code, so "false" won't even be necessary? Since the empty spots make it kinda confusing. Is it even possible with the limitations of the libraries I mentioned? (btw. if I am asking for too much, feel free not to help out anymore. You already did ALOT more for me than I could hope for. I will still try to think of a method to get rid of the "I need to display false to make it work properly")